# problems detecting Asus nexus 7 on Windows 7 Home Professional (driver installation problem)

Tags: adb, nexus-7, usb-drivers

I am having problems getting my Asus Nexus 7 detected on a laptop with Windows 7 Home Professional
When I connect the device to the computer, it says USB debugging mode enabled, but the computer does not detect it as adb device, MTP or camera, and it is displayed as a Nexus 7 with an exclamation mark in Device Manager.
[I went to this website](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus%207&p=20&s=16), but the drop down menu called OS does not show any options for some reason. [After reading this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/problem-connecting-nexus-7-as-mass-storage-device-on-windows-7), I seem to remember that I had to install Windows Media Player 11 on another computer running Windows XP to get it to detect the Android device. Is there any way to do this without having to download Media Player 11 in this computer? Why isn't driver for Windows 7 available at the Asus website? Or is there any other location from where I can download it?

Comment: We had that question already a couple of times. AFAIR Koushik Dutta's [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/) often proved helpful.