# How can I transfer some files from my Google Pixel 6 (Android 12) to a Microsoft Windows 7 laptop via a USB cable?

Tags: usb, file-transfer, windows, android-12, google-pixel-6

I am trying to transferring some files from my Google Pixel 6 (Android 12) to a Microsoft Windows 7 laptop via a USB cable (USB-C to USB-A). I don't see the Google Pixel 6 in Windows Explorer:

[image]

whereas I do see my Samsung Galaxy S9 (Android 10) when using the same laptop and same USB cable:

[image]

I did enable file transfer on the Google Pixel 6:

[image]

and I did see some driver being installed when plugging the Google Pixel 6 to my computer:

[image]

What could be the issue?

---

After further investigations, Windows 7 does see the Pixel 6 in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This makes me wonder whether the issue is this old driver. But I don't know how to update it.

The  phone also shows up in `Device Manager` as `Google Nexus ADB Interface`:

[image]

or via tree view:

[image]

Using [USBDeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html):

[image]

Comment: Maybe try updating the drivers from [the official Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you, I tried, but I can't update them: [How I update the Google USB Driver on a Windows 7 laptop?](https://superuser.com/q/1696225/116475). However in insight those are just adb drivers: I don't think we need for transferring files, right?

Comment: AFAIK, it still needs a proper driver to detect. Looking from [a related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/30111/44325) (similar brand but different model, Nexus 7), you probably could check the driver configuration from the Windows side.

Comment: Searching for `ClockworkMod Android Windows driver` brings up a [project](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver) whose last update was 5 years ago. You may want to uninstall, reboot and install with Google driver in case of conflict.

Comment: Change the device manager to show the tree by connection. Then check if you see all USB devices of your phone. If ADB is enabled and USB file sharing you should see three devices: one compound device which has two children, the USB MTP device and a ADB interface. If not you may have installed the ADB driver to the wrong device node (the compound device?).

Comment: @Robert thank you here is the tree  view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/53srx.png Only 1 device visible (Google Nexus ADB Interface).

Comment: Was the device screen locked or unlocked (with active USB MTP)? If it was unlocked with active USB then the USB driver are not installed correctly (then the device should use the "USB composite driver" exactly as the device below).

Comment: @Robert unlocked with active USB. How to install the USB driver correctly?

Comment: Delete the device ADB interface node in device manager, then unplug and replug the phone, make sure adb and MTP are enabled then check device manager for the three device nodes, select the adb node and install the correct driver.